# Querying database comparing cell from Excel file using C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am trying to see if this cell in my excel spreadsheet is the PK in the database. I am using Aspose for bring in the excel file (this works). I know the connection string is working as well.

I am wanting to query the database for this code. If this code brings a row back, I want the flag to be true. If no rows come back, I want to move on since the flag is already set to false. I tried it and I keep getting true ever though that code isn't in the database. Can someone help me to get this working properly? Or is there a simpler way to get this task achieved?

```
#region StateCharges_Status
public static bool StateCharges_Status(DataRow dr) {
    bool ok = StateCharges_Exists(dr);
    if (ok)
        return StateCharges_Update(dr);
    else
        return StateCharges_Insert(dr);
}
#endregion

#region StateCharges_Exists
private static bool StateCharges_Exists(DataRow dr) {
    bool flag = false;
    Database pbkDB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("PbKConnectionString");
    DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@"Select * from tblCtStateCharges where code = '{0}'", dr["Code"].ToString()));
    try {
        pbkDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
        flag = true; // <-- I guess this is where it needs something added.
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    return flag;
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the query to something like:

```
 DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@"Select count(*) as cnt      from tblCtStateCharges where code = '{0}'", dr["Code"].ToString()));
```

There is no need to select every field when you only care if the record exists.

Then you change the

```
 pbkDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
```

to something like

```
 int count = (int)pbkDB.ExecuteScalar(dbCommand);
```

Then change the setting of flag to (you won't need the if anymore)

```
  flag = count > 0;
```

So the new code would look something like

```
 private static bool StateCharges_Exists(DataRow dr) {
 bool flag = false;
 Database pbkDB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("PbKConnectionString");
 DbCommand dbCommand = pbkDB.GetSqlStringCommand(string.Format(@"Select count(*) as cnt from   tblCtStateCharges where code = '{0}'", dr["Code"].ToString()));
 try {
    int count = (int)pbkDB.ExecuteScalar(dbCommand);
   flag = count > 0; 
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
 }
 return flag;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you should use the ExecuteQuery-method which returns a IEnumerable.

then you can test for result by writing:

```
var result = pbkDB.ExecuteQuery(dbCommand);
flag = result.Count() > 0;
```

Comment: I am getting an error. "Cannot resolve symbol 'ExecuteQuery' Active hotspot in live template session"